# How do I create and array with two heads and LOTS of members

Tags: powershell

Preface: Please tell me a better way of doing this if you know of any! Even if it changes everything.

I have a powershell script that works with Net-SNMP to store the current value of an OID, change it and then check and store the values. Right now the previous and new values are stored in their own variable. There are about 160 OIDs that I need to change on >1000 nodes in my environment.

For Example for Previous and New values:

```
$P_vpwrSystemTempCompensation_0 = & '.\SnmpGet.exe' -q -r:"$ip" -v:2c -c:public -o:.1.3.6.1.4.1.13858.2.2.1.0
$N_vpwrSystemTempCompensation_0 = & '.\SnmpGet.exe' -q -r:"$ip" -v:2c -c:public -o:.1.3.6.1.4.1.13858.2.2.1.0
```

I'm try to figure the best way to store these and output into an CSV. I would like it to be formatted liked this:

[image]

Each CSV will be saved with the name and IP of the node I'm hitting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it sounds like you should create an array containing PSCustomObjects.  After which you can output directly to CSV with the Usual Export-CSV...  However, if you are doing this for many machines the table would probably be formatted differently...

Comment: You are correct. That is what i'm looking to do and I'm able to do it now BUT it create columns of data instead of rows of data... if that make sense. Like this...

Its like this right now when I get the object's details:
Member1: PrevData
|
Member160: PrevData

Then starts over for my New Data

Member1: NewData
|
Member160: NewData

----
When I export to CSV, the first row is all the members and all rows after that is the data. This does not seem right. I'm trying to make the first column the member and all other column after that the data. 

Clear as mud, yeah?

Comment: You should really [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59313590/edit) your question to include things like sample data and code. It is hard to format things like that in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object like this in a loop, and that could be exported to csv:

```
$oid = 'vpwrSystemTempCompensation.0'
$prev = 2
$new = 4647
[pscustomobject]@{OID=$oid; Previous=$prev; New=$new}

OID                          Previous  New
---                          --------  ---
vpwrSystemTempCompensation.0        2 5647
```

By the way, you don't need the call operator to run smnpget, if you don't put it in quotes:

```
 .\SnmpGet.exe -q -r:$ip -v:2c -c:public -o:.1.3.6.1.4.1.13858.2.2.1.0
```